# Running script through command

Tags: bash, shell, security, unix

I'm trying to decode my password through a script while it's being run but it seems like the script is being run with a literal and the password is not processed. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
#!/bin/bash
MYENC="Tk9UX1RIQVRfU1RVUElEX0xPTAo="

rdesktop -u FOO -d mgmt -p 'echo $(echo $MYENC) | base64 --decode' 192.0.0.0
```

I also tried to just pass in a variable but that failed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYENC="Tk9UX1RIQVRfU1RVUElEX0xPTAo="

rdesktop -u FOO -d mgmt -p $(echo $MYENC | base64 --decode) 192.0.0.0
```

Note that I wrapped the juicy stuff `echo...base64...` in `$(...)`. This is called "command substitution" - basically you're telling bash that you want the code inside the `$(...)` to be executed before the rest of the line, with the result substituted in its place. More info here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

Comment: Recommend the use of `$(…)` in place of back quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Or this

```
#!/bin/bash
MYENC="Tk9UX1RIQVRfU1RVUElEX0xPTAo="
rdesktop -u FOO -d mgmt -p $(base64 --decode <<< "$MYENC") 192.0.0.0
```